# WebAuthenticationBroker AuthenticateAsync returning Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#-4.0, win-universal-app

We are trying out Universal Windows Application, in that trying to open a browser request using WebAuthenticationBroker class AuthenticateAsync method. Below is the code we written.

```
WebAuthenticationResult wabResult; 
var wabOptions = WebAuthenticationOptions.UseHttpPost;
wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl), new Uri(options.EndUrl));
options.StartUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/b9545c46-ac5b-4245-b947-636bce5385ea/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=0bcf1588-48a7-4ffd-82ef-5a5d2ad770c5&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+0bcf1588-48a7-4ffd-82ef-5a5d2ad770c5&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8989%2F&nonce=9a7ca44c3f51aa2f5430bae79c4f3a803f4f32cb8d6c4bd0828302d15e6840bedb01cc448e801429b1c90f4994a9081161549df166e8368f5f68123758306cb3&response_mode=form_post&code_challenge=F_HVm_Nk35wEzpyKhU5qFahh69RbF7yIoa0rDf2KTps&code_challenge_method=S256&p=B2C_1_sign_in_wpf'
options.EndUrl = http://localhost:8989/
```

When debugger reaches above statement it giving error: **Value does not fall within the expected range.**

What exactly this error is?

Below is the stack trace of the exception

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at IdentityModel.OidcClient.WebView.Uwp.UwpWebView.d__5.MoveNext()
```

If we try with out redirect URI, applicaiton opening browser and we able to do all the tasks in that browser but result not returning into the application.

Can any one help us out!

Comment: Hi @ramakrishna, I'm encountering the same issue, are you able to find a fix for it?